# Print PDF with breadcrumb by Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, charts

I am new with Microsoft Graph API and wanted to print PDF document uploaded on OneDrive. I am using below code to view the document but not getting the API to print the document directly:

```cs
var permission = await this._graphServiceClient.Users[Email].Drive.Items[itemId]
    .CreateLink("view","anonymous",new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)))
    .Request().PostAsync();
if (permission != null && permission.Link != null)
{
    return permission.Link.WebUrl.ToString();
}
```

This is returning the link which is being open the document in view mode,
[image]

I also wanted to provide the print functionality to open PDF in print format in browser the same functionality given by browser for printing, I want this functionality to get all breadcurmb attached with PDF (shown below).
[image]